# FlashFirebug inspector can't find swfs

Tags: flash, firebug

I'm trying to debug a page with multiple swfs on it. However, when I go to the FlashFirebug inspector and have it scan for swf files, it turns up nothing. But, if I look on the right hand panel, under SWFs, it seems to have found all of them perfectly. Also, the console and every other part of flash firebug seems to be able to find and work with these swfs just fine.

How can I get the inspector to find the swfs that the rest of the add-on can?

Here's what I'm running this on:

- Firefox 15.0.1
- Firebug 1.10.3
- FlashFirebug 4.49
- Flash 11.4.402.265 Debug version for Mac
- Mac OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.2)

I've tried this on some other sites and was able to use the inspector just fine, so I know it does work. Also, since I work on this site, I know that the swfs are as3 files.

Thanks for any advice you can give

Answer (score 0):

Author of FlashFirebug here, send me the site that contains these undetectable SWFs (use contact form). I'm assuming you know for sure they're AS3. Because the inspector only works with AS3 SWFs.

Comment: Hi, I have this issue too. SWF (AS3) on localhost can not be inspected.

Answer (score 0):

No answer really, but the same thing happens to me on: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html

The neroli.swf, fonts.swf and shareScreen.swf appear under the "SWF" tab on the right, but the Inspector says "Click here to scan for AS3 SWF files." and after clicking: "No AS3 SWF files detected on this page."  This happens on my own local app that the inspector works for sometimes too (but mostly does not work).  FF16.0.2, WinXP64, Firebug 1.10.6 FlashFirebug 4.55.

A forum on the o-minds site would be nice too.